# Хостинг для телеграмм бота с селениум

Tags: python, selenium

подскажите пожалуйста, какие еще есть бесплатные (или с оплатой российской картой) облачные сервисы для хостинга телеграмм бота на python с селениум, так как завтра, как я понимаю, heroku прекращает бесплатный хостинг

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь [со справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). На StackOverflow можно задавать вопросы насчёт серверов, но только об их настройке. Для поиска же используйте всеми известные решения поисковых движков ([Google](https://google.com/), [Yandex](https://yandex.ru/), [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Если знаете Linux или все никак не доходили руки начать работать с ним, то можете любым VDS хостингом воспользоваться. Например, VDSina (~200 р./мес, есть возможность в ЕС хоститься) или Яндекс.Облако (~500 р./мес).

1. Получаете машину
2. Подключаетесь по ssh
3. Устанавливаете python
4. Запускаете процесс через командную строку
5. Profit :)